# Why is there more than one command in Bash for accomplishing the same task?

Tags: command-line, users

I've read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75333/why-doesnt-w-or-who-command-show-all-logged-in-users), but it doesn't address the issue of redundancy.

As an example, I've noticed that there are three different commands for returning logged in users:

- `w` (?)
- `who` (print all usernames currently logged in)<sup>1</sup>
- `users` (list users currently logged in)<sup>1</sup>

I know the output is slightly different, but is there an actual use case for having the redundancy in this example? Wouldn't it be better to have a single command with multiple parameters? I guess the question comes down to whether there is a policy in place that prevents merging of Bash commands and whether there is an index of the most appropriate commands to use when commands overlap in function.

<sup>1</sup> Purpose according to this [index](http://ss64.com/bash/) of bash commands.

**Edit in reponse to [on hold]:**

I'm not asking for opinions. I'm asking why there are commands that overlap because it's confusing. I want to know which commands are the best commands to use when commands overlap. I'm not negating personal taste. I know some people prefer certain software. @Rinzwind mentioned in the comments that my question is probably about backward compatibility and I think he is right. Is there a systematic way to include or exclude certain Bash commands in each new version of Ubuntu so that people like myself who were not involved since the Unix days can get maximum benefit from the OS?

Comment: That's Linux and Linux is a free system.

Comment: @A.B. Then there must be something that prevents developers from spawning more similar commands.

Comment: There is no need for "Something". If you need restrictions, use Microsoft, Apple or something else.

Comment: @A.B. My concern is with whether similar commands violate the DRY principal.

Comment: That are no *Bash* commands. That are commands for a terminal, without a GUI.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is likely the answer.  We inherited all commands from all kinds of previous systems (aka. Unix).

Comment: @Rinzwind It makes sense that backward compatibility compliance would lead to some commands being less useful than others.

Answer (score 5):

### It's called freedom!

It is the freedom to use what you think is right. It is the freedom to be creative. The freedom to not have to endure limitations of software companies. It is the freedom of having to think for themselves.

**It's Linux!**

Probably most of the programs are older than you and have their origins in Unix. But what is old, is not automatically bad.

---

And as you say in your comments:

> My concern is with whether similar commands violate the DRY principal.

This has nothing to do with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Don't repeat yourself in **your code**, that's right. But **fork code** and **change code**; be creative!

If you need restrictions, use Microsoft, Apple or something else, but not Linux.

---

Read more here: [Linux, GNU, and freedom](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/linux-gnu-freedom.en.html).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As a relatively new Ubuntu user, I'm just questioning the criteria by which Bash versions are included in Ubuntu distros.

Comment: @SANBIsamples if this doesn't answer your question you should state it differently.

Comment: @SANBIsamples your question has absolutely nothing to do with bash. Those commands are simple programs designed to run in a terminal emulator - the fact that you are using bash rather than ksh or fish or whatever is really rather irrelevant.